# How could I be subscribed (by email) to my questions?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, notifications, email

How could I be subscribed (by email) to MY QUESTIONS? As for others questions, I can click on FOLLOW, but on my question page, there is no such link...

Is there some setting in My profile, which would subscribe me automatically to any questions/answers, which I post?